# Whats wrong with this SQL query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL on my web app, and trying to create a table call "tblSpend" and will be having the following columns in my table

- itemID (integer, primary key, autoincrement)
- fullDate (TEXT)
- ItemAmount (REAL)
- ItemDes (TEXT)

And here's my query :

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSpend (ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,fullDate TEXT, ItemAmount REAL, ItemDes TEXT)

and i got the error message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near 'AUTOINCREMENT, fullDate TEXT , ItemAmount REAL, ItemDes TEXT)' at line 1**

Got any idea?

Comment: I'm confused here...are you using SQLite or MySQL?  In either case, just poke around on Google for 30 seconds and you will realize what the syntax errors are.

Comment: *Got any ideas?* Yes. First, figure out that you're using MySQL and not SQLite. Then *check the manual that corresponds to your **MySQL** server version for the right syntax*. Seriously?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am using SQLite, i am new to this and i have been researching for a while, would you like to point out what the problem is ?

Comment: You are **NOT** using SQLite, because the error message clearly says **your MySQL version**. Google *MySQL documentation*.

Comment: No need AUTOINCREMENT ,Primary key in SQLite is always auto incremented.

Comment: @ZahidRahman Except this isn't SQLite.

Comment: @ZahidRahman: Read the post. The user is not using SQLite. They're using MySQL, and it is useless to try to help them until they can figure out what they're trying to do.

Comment: @zahidRahman i have figured it out thanks for your help :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing an underscore in "AUTOINCREMENT":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSpend (ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,fullDate TEXT, ItemAmount REAL, ItemDes TEXT)
```

Comment: **YOU ARE RIGHT**, i was so careless. Everything works fine now!